# Mysql объединить два запроса в один из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql, база-данных, запрос, select

Доброго времени суток! Я пытаюсь выбрать из двух таблиц в один запрос данные.
Собственно говоря нужно получить - `nook.*, jurnal.company, jurnal.tara, WHERE nook.parent = jurnal.id` и `jurnal.date` - который находится в другой строке БД, но эта строка связанна по `jurnal.parent`. 
Я составил два запроса, которые получают те данные, которые мне нужны, но никак не могу понять как их объединить в один!

```
SELECT nook.*, jurnal.company, jurnal.tara
FROM nook, jurnal
WHERE nook.parent = jurnal.id
AND nook.spisan is NULL
OR nook.spisan = 0


SELECT jurnal.date 
FROM jurnal
WHERE jurnal.id IN
(SELECT jurnal.parent
FROM nook, jurnal
WHERE nook.parent = jurnal.id)
```

Думаю для магистров труда не составит помочь новичку советом)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте JOIN. Он позволяет в том числе и соединять таблицу с самой собой. Это даёт возможность соединять данные из разных строк таблицы в одну строку результата запроса. Только стоит использовать псевдонимы, чтобы не запутаться.

```
SELECT n.*, j1.company, j1.tara, j2.date
FROM nook n
     JOIN jurnal j1 ON n.parent = j1.id
     JOIN jurnal j2 ON j2.id = j1.parent
WHERE 
     n.spisan is NULL
     OR n.spisan = 0;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Лучше поздно чем никогда ))). Эту проблему уже решил самостоятельно.